# Set ref if condition is truthy

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have been looking for a clean solution to setting refs if a condition is truthy but haven't seen a good solution yet.

I was to do something like the following (sort of pseudo-code):

```
<ul>
   {this.items.map((item) => {
      return (
         <li ref={item.isActive === true ? 'activeItem' : null}>
            {item.name}
         </li>
      ); 
   })}
</ul>
```

I just haven't seen anywhere what the value of ref should be if I don't want to set the ref or maybe this is just an anti-pattern and someone has another way of doing this.

Comment: this seems fine to me. Is it not working or what's the issue?

Comment: This does seem pretty clean.

Comment: Just wasn't sure whether setting null for the ref was the preferred solution. Thanks @chris

Answer (score 1):

Although your solution seems fine, if you prefer another approach you could try:

```
<ul>
   {this.items.map((item) => {
     if(item.isActive) {
       return (
         <li ref='activeItem'>
           {item.name}
         </li>
        );
     } else {
       return (
         <li>
           {item.name}
         </li>
       );
     }
   })}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the `key` property in your map function!

If really it looks ugly to you or you need a lot of these conditions in your code, you can define a small helper to make the job

```
const onlyIf = (condition, value) => condition ? value : null

<ul>
   {this.items.map((item, key)=>
     <li key={key} ref={onlyIf(item.isActive, 'activeItem')}>
       {item.name}
     </li>
    )}
</ul>
```

But yes, your solution is fine